# Google Sheets formula to concatenate column headers into a list delimited by "|", transpose it, repeat list N times

Tags: google-sheets, concatenation, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, google-sheets-query

I'm trying to concatenate all employee names in the attached Google form entry here (https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1S1HkO-a-xP09hZWbVsB7OeCc0KI_s3j9pwWh-N7S2Gg/edit?usp=sharing)
provided into a list delimited by "|" then use count, address and arrayformula to repeat concatenation over all cells with names in them, repeat this delimited list of names N times based on the count of number of rows in the form in "attendance by worker sheet" then split this repeated list by the "|" delimiter, to give me one cell per name and one group of names per date.

Finally, I want to transpose then paste this output down a column as shown in "desired output sheet". I want it to be automatic such that whenever an entry is made in the "attendance by worker form" it automatically updates in the "desired output sheet" 
I have tried

```
=Transpose(split(REPT('attendance by worker'!C1&"|", 4),"|"))
```

because I am a beginner but it is still far from what I want.

expected results as in file attached

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you kind of need to do it like this:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(SPLIT(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(
 IF('attendance by worker'!C3:Z<>"", 
 "♦"&'attendance by worker'!A3:A&"♥"&'attendance by worker'!C1:Z1&"♥"&'attendance by worker'!C3:Z, ))
 ,,999^99)),,999^99), "♦")), "♥"))
```

[image: 0]

#### [spreadsheet demo](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Aeqj000xmu3KZy91xMLDyZWXg5YR_ux4oV6szd0_D-o/edit#gid=1778409213&range=A2)

Comment: i want to ask a beginners question. what does " ,,999^99)),,999^99) in the formula represent? where can i get more information about using it so i can read more about it.

Comment: it means kind of nothing. it's just an unreasonably big number. the issue would be if those two numbers were small - queries would not work correctly and output would be unpredictable. try changing `999^99` for `5` and you will see why it needs to be big number